# Clever use of DownValues, or failure to understand the "Mathematica Way."

Tags: functions, evaluation, code-review

I needed to look at the changes in the values of about 4000 items from one year to the next.  I have a table with identifiers and values for each year. Not all of the items are in each list. The tables contain the following rows, with more data to the right. 
[image]
So I did the following:

```
govnew = Select[data[[2 ;;, {2, 3, 4, 6}]], #[[4]] > 0 &];  
govold = Select[dataold[[2 ;;, {2, 3, 4, 6}]], #[[4]] > 0 &];  
intersection = Intersection[govnew[[All, 1]], govold[[All, 1]]];   
Clear[both];  
Map[(both[#] = 1) &, intersection];  
govnew2 = Select[govnew, both[#[[1]]] == 1 &];   
govold2 = Select[govold, both[#[[1]]] == 1 &];
```

Which reduced the two lists to the intersection of the identifiers in both lists. It worked. But it reduces a list of Down Values to a dictionary. Doesn't use a *Mathematica* function in a secret and powerful way. Is there a more *Mathematica* like approach.

Comment: Could you please provide some dummy (or actual) data? btw, `Scan` is more typical and cleaner instead of your `Map` above.

Comment: @rm-rf FWIW I'm using `{data, dataold} = List @@ RandomInteger[12, {2, 20, 6}];`

Comment: +1 - Great use of DownValues.  Nice!  P.S., How's life?  Time to actually get together. Best.

Comment: @rm-rf I never use scan. I'll find out what it does.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly fine use of `DownValues`. An alternative might be to join the lists, then `GatherBy[combinedlist,First]` or something along those lines. Now discard all singletons.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This appears to be a perfectly legitimate use of `DownValues`.  These are often used by experienced users as a hash table.

There are some ways you might improve this.

First, you could use the value `True` directly, and it's arguably better to `Scan` than to `Map`, but I've used the latter often enough myself as it rarely matters.

```
Scan[(both[#] = True) &, intersection];

govnew2 = Select[govnew, both[#[[1]]] &]
```

This `DownValues` hash table is often very fast as should not be dismissed.  You can however do this more simply with `Alternatives`, e.g.:

```
pat = Alternatives @@ intersection;

govnew2 = Cases[govnew, {pat, __}]
govold2 = Cases[govold, {pat, __}]
```

Regarding the first part of your code, `Pick` can usually be faster though in this case also longer:

```
govnew = Pick[data[[2 ;;, {2, 3, 4, 6}]], Sign @ data[[2 ;;, 6]], 1]
```

---

**A note regarding `Alternatives`**

As mentioned above it is important to know that `Alternatives` is not a replacement for the DownValues.  Alternatives are checked *in order* and therefore the time taken for a match will be proportionate to the number of alternatives.  For applications involving a large number it will be much faster to use either DownValues or a `Rule` table optimized with `Dispatch`.  For example:

```
range = Range[1*^5];
nums = RandomSample[range, 5000];
alts = Alternatives @@ nums;
Scan[(test[#] = True) &, nums];

Select[range, test] // Timing // First
Cases[range, alts]  // Timing // First
```

> 0.049
>
> 5.289

Comment: I see that True makes sense. Then I could just Select[govnew, both[#[[1]]] &], right?  And I don't think I've ever used Alternatives. That would be closer to pure "Mathematica" code.

Comment: PS. I find myself wanting to use the word "Mathematical" to mean more like a Mathematica way of doing it, but it doesn't mean that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @rm-rf
  Thanks, everyone!!

Comment: Mathematicaish? (Maybe not..)

Comment: @George How about *Wolfish*?  :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just used Alternatives[] in another application. It's elegant and clean. It's, it's ... Mathematicalicious!

Comment: @George I added a short warning about `Alternatives` that you should read.  Please don't let it dissuade you from using this function, but rather be aware of when it is and isn't appropriate.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 9):

The example below indicates what I had in mind with a comment to use `Join` and `GatherBy`. It also shows that this is roughly comparable to using DownValues.

Set up an example:

```
n = 6;
l1 = RandomInteger[10^n, {7*10^(n - 1), 2}];
l2 = RandomInteger[10^n, {7*10^(n - 1), 2}];
l1b = Map[First, GatherBy[l1, First]];
l2b = Map[First, GatherBy[l2, First]];
```

Using `Join` and `GatherBy`:

```
Timing[
 l3 = Select[GatherBy[Join[l1b, l2b], First], Length[#] == 2 &];]

(* Out[178]= {2.360000, Null} *)
```

Using `DownValues`:

```
govnew = l1b;
govold = l2b;
Clear[both];
Timing[intersection = 
  Intersection[govnew[[All, 1]], govold[[All, 1]]]; 
 Scan[(both[#] = 1) &, intersection]; 
 govnew2 = Select[govnew, both[#[[1]]] == 1 &]; 
 govold2 = Select[govold, both[#[[1]]] == 1 &];]

(* Out[189]= {3.780000, Null} *)
```

Quick check:

```
Sort[l3][[All, 1, 1]] === Sort[govold2][[All, 1]] === 
 Sort[govnew2][[All, 1]]

(* Out[207]= True *)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is another problem that used to be kind of a pain back before *Mathematica* 10, but is now dramatically simplified by `Association`s and the related functions:

```
CompareRows[tables:{___List}] := MapThread[SortBy, 
   {(Apply[Join]) @* Values /@ KeyIntersection[GroupBy[First] /@ 
       tables], PositionIndex /@ tables}];
```

The `SortBy`/[`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html) combination makes sure the rows come out in their original order. Then it's an easy matter to reproduce your results:

```
{govold2, govnew2} = CompareRows[{data, dataold}];
```

Even better, this new version works with any number of data sets for comparison, and doing so required zero extra effort on my part.