# Alternatives ordering affects pattern matching in Cases?

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

Given

```
expr = f[x, g[y], z]
```

In the following query, the pattern `h_[__, c_]` appears as last slot in `Alternatives`:

```
Cases[expr, (h_[c_] | h_[c_, __] | h_[__, c_, __] | h_[__, c_]) :> 
  h -> c, {0, Infinity}]
```

Gives

```
{g -> y, f -> x}
```

Ie, "f[__,z]" is not matched but is matched when the pattern is rotated to the first slot:

```
Cases[expr, (h_[__, c_] | h_[c_] | h_[c_, __] | h_[__, c_, __]) :> 
  h -> c, {0, Infinity}]
```

Which gives:

```
{g -> y, f -> z}
```

Souldn't `Alternatives` be commutative? Apparentely only the first match per level is returned. Is there a method to return `x, y` and `z` containing patterns?

Comment: What result are you seeking to obtain, precisely?

Comment: {f->x,f->g,f->z,g->y}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Patterns in [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html) are tried in order
- Only the first pattern that matches is "applied" to the expression.
- `Cases` does not support multiple patterns outside of `Alternatives`.

I suppose it could be interesting to debate that design decision but nevertheless that's the way it works at this time.

You could of course search with multiple passes:

```
expr = f[x, g[y], z]
pat = h_[c_] | h_[c_, __] | h_[__, c_, __] | h_[__, c_];

Join @@ (Cases[expr, # :> h -> c, {0, -1}] & /@ List @@ pat)
```

> ```
> {g -> y, f -> x, f -> g[y], f -> z}
> ```

Or using `ReplaceList` and `Level`:

```
rules = # :> h -> c & /@ List @@ pat
Join @@ (ReplaceList[#, rules] & /@ Level[expr, {0, -1}])
```

Since neither of these is efficient you could subvert the normal evaluation by using side-effects, e.g. with `Condition`:

```
Module[{f},
  f[pat] := 1 /; Sow[h -> c];
  Reap[Scan[f, expr, {0, -1}]][[2, 1]]
]
```

> ```
> {g -> y, f -> x, f -> g[y], f -> z}
> ```

Or more cleanly, though perhaps rather enigmatically, using `Cases` itself:

```
Reap[Cases[expr, pat :> 1 /; Sow[h -> c], {0, -1}];][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {g -> y, f -> x, f -> g[y], f -> z}
> ```

Finally, if traversal order is irrelevant:

```
Reap[expr /. pat :> 1 /; Sow[h -> c]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {f -> x, f -> g[y], f -> z, g -> y}
> ```

---

A note regarding another ramification of `Alternatives` is here:

- [Clever use of DownValues, or failure to understand the "Mathematica Way."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29054/clever-use-of-downvalues-or-failure-to-understand-the-mathematica-way/29055#29055)

---

**NOTE:** It looks like my assumptions about efficiency were wrong, and the multi-pass method may be more efficient than the rest.  I need to explore this further but I have neither the time nor the interest right now.

Comment: In the last two instances I think you could simplify `pat = h_[___, c_, ___]`, too.

Comment: @mfvonh Great point, but I was assuming the given patterns were merely toy examples and I did not wish to tamper with them.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks, this is great. But how to modify so that the output only matches heads like 'f->g' rather than f->g[y]'

Comment: @mfvonh, I tried h_[___, c_, ___] but it didn't work.

Comment: @alancalvitti Why shouldn't `f -> g[y]` be included?  Because `g[y]` is not atomic?  Because `g[y]` has already matched a pattern?  Something else?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I need `h -> If[AtomQ[c], c, Head[c]]`. Actually a modification for a specific application that I will ask about next

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I accepted your answer b/c it works on the example I provided. However, doesn't seem to generalize, eg, applied to f[x, g[y[a, b], w, w2, w3], z] misses w2. Can you modify your approach to handle this case or should I ask a separate Q?

Comment: @alancalvitti I think the input/output you desire is separate from the specific question here about `Alternatives`; I suggest posting a new question containing merely a clear description of the output you want for a given input, allowing responders to detach their answers from `Alternatives` if appropriate.  (Thanks for the Accept.)

Answer (score 2):

```
Flatten@{Head[expr] -> # & /@ Level[expr, {1}], 
  Thread[Cases[expr, x_[_] -> x] -> Cases[expr, _[x_] -> x]]}
```